# facebook v2.2 current_location is missing (no fql)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Before version 2.1 i was using fql to get user public information using the following code.

"https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select uid,name,current_location from user where uid = xxx"

Then i would parse the country, state and city from the response.
without fql we are using location field which leads to a page and the page gives longitude and latitude.
How do i get the country in v2.2 (The name or country code)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the location with Graph API using /user

refer to below link.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dlocation&version=v2.2&

Comment: i need the country or country code. The normal user location gives you a page id of you city or hometown. i don't think i can get the country from that page. With the FQL the current_location gave the country name.

Comment: hmmm you're right, well so what I think you can do, from that user location you can get the city ID, then do query on that ID, so you'll get Lat, Long and with those values you can use google maps API

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=20.6667,-103.333&sensor=true

should exist an easier way... those Facebook devs should bring back FQL..... :(